# Failed to activate systemd-timesyncd.service

Tags: systemd, directory, ntp, exit-status

I've scanned all forums and questions and found no working answer to my problem. 
The Network Time Synchronization service doesn't work. The timedatectl service seems to work just fine without it though but it shows that the systemd-timesyncd is not active

```
torof@OMEN:~$ timedatectl status
                  Local time: Fri 2019-02-08 15:12:47 CET
              Universal time: Fri 2019-02-08 14:12:47 UTC
                    RTC time: Fri 2019-02-08 14:12:47
                   Time zone: Europe/Paris (CET, +0100)
   System clock synchronized: yes
   systemd-timesyncd.service active: no
             RTC in local TZ: no
```

The `libnss-systemd` is already installed.

I have checked the syslog but couldn't figure out the problem, enabled and restarted service to no avail.

```
torof@OMEN:~$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-02-08 13:57:04 CET; 13min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
  Process: 4383 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd (code=exited, status=238/STATE_DIRECTORY)
 Main PID: 4383 (code=exited, status=238/STATE_DIRECTORY)

Feb 08 13:57:04 OMEN systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=238/STATE_DIRECTORY
Feb 08 13:57:04 OMEN systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 13:57:04 OMEN systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
Feb 08 13:57:04 OMEN systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
Feb 08 13:57:04 OMEN systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 08 13:57:04 OMEN systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
Feb 08 13:57:04 OMEN systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 08 13:57:04 OMEN systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 13:57:04 OMEN systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
```

What is going wrong, where to find the problem and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [systemd Github issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7659) lists a comment with a [workaround](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7659#issuecomment-352724406):

```
chmod 0700 /var/lib/private
```

Comment: That was it, but even reading the github issue I don't understand what was happening, do you ?
If yes could you help me to ?
Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: It [looks like the fix was merged into systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/7663#issuecomment-352719571), so I'd expect distributions to pick up the fix eventually. Looks to me like it was a bug in error-checking of the directory-making functions, but I haven't traced my way all the way through it.

Comment: Unfortunately on my system, with the same error, that directory already had those permissions and trying to set them again changed nothing. Guess I'll have to keep looking